# Extract internal calendar regressors in RJDemetra

Tags: r

Excuse me but this is the first time that I use RJDemetra in R. I am generating a model to seasonally adjust using the rjdemetra package and its x13_spec and later x13 function. I would like to know how I can extract the internal regressors used for example by the calculation of tradingdays.option = "WorkingDays" or when we mark easter.enabled = TRUE.
Thank you so much.

Example of code:

```
myseries <- ipi_c_eu[, "FR"]
myspec2 <- x13_spec(spec = "RSA5c", 
             tradingdays.option = "WorkingDays",
             transform.function = "None")
 myreg2 <- x13(myseries, myspec2)
```

Answer (score 0):

the tradingday regressors are shown in
`myreg2$regarima$model` --> tde (second column)

and the holiday regressors are shown in
`myreg2$regarima$model` --> ee (third column).

Note that the regressors are centered around the seasonal mean, i.e. these are shown as deviations from the respective month's average. This is because the average effect of the number of working days in a month is considered a seasonal effect and only the deviations from this average is the calendaric effect.